# writing an archive that contains encrypted files

Tags: libarchive

I've some files that are encrypted with nettle.
when I read the archive, they're all messed up... so is there's a preferred filter/format in order to keep those files straight?

best regards,
nicolas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your first question.  Please consider adding some more detail to clarify your question, perhaps a code excerpt that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish and an example of how they are "all messed up."

Answer (score 0):

problem solved...
I was not reading files to put in archive in binary mode.

what a great library :)

++